# Java 8 Update 91 Issue

Tags: javascript, java, applet, liveconnect

While applet initializing when using isActive() method. It only return undefined. This problem only comes "Java 8 Update 91". Can anyone tel me the solution to fine applet loaded or not?

I have used the following code:

```
function isAppletActive(app) {
 var active = false; 
 try { active = app.isActive(); // IE check }
 catch(ex) { 
 try { active = app.isActive; // Firefox check }
   catch(ex1){ } } //alert(active); return active; 
}
```

Comment: This appears to be a bug in Firefox 45 under Windows; the applet functions are no longer accessible from Javascript.

Comment: @Aurasphere: No, it's Javascript code trying to interact with Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in either Firefox (most likely) or Java 8_91. It appears that any premature call to the applet's method hoses the link to the applet permanently.

However, the applet support has a new feature for checking applet status, enabled by setting parameter `<param name="java_status_events" value="true"/>`. This in turn allows `status` to be checked while the applet is loading. If you enable this, and use it to prevent any applet method being called until the applet loads, it all works.

```
function isAppletActive(app) {
    // assuming `app` is the applet element...
    if(app.status==1) { return false; } // still loading
    if(app.status==2) { throw "Applet load failed"; }

    try { active = app.isActive(); } // IE check 
    catch(ex) { 
        try { active = app.isActive; } // Firefox check 
        catch(ex1) { /* NEVER swallow exceptions! */ } 
    } 
    //alert(active); 
    return active;
}
```

And just BTW, Firefox uses `app.isActive()`, not `app.isActive`, though who knows what it did in the past.

Comment: You're welcome. Had just encountered this myself when I found your question.